# Tomcat thread suspend 15m26s

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, suspend

Got an issue, log as below:

- 19:25:03 Thread **11** log A
- 19:25:03 Thread **12** log A
- 19:25:04 Thread 13 log A
- 19:25:04 Thread 13 log B
- 19:25:04 Thread 13 log C ....
- 19:25:05 Thread 14 log A
- 19:25:05 Thread 14 log B
- 19:25:05 Thread 14 log C ....
- ...
- 19:40:29 Thread **11** log B
- 19:40:29 Thread **12** log B

The thread 11 & thread 12 suspend for **15 minutes and 26 seconds** in the log, from log step A to log step B.

Between log step A to log step B, there is only a database query to MySQL SQL server use hibernate.

Server background: JRE 8, Tomcat 1.8, there is another tomcat 1.7 in same server running on JRE 6.

Hibernate configuration:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">@HIBERNATE-DIALECT@</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Data source:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://<db url>"/>
<property name="username" value="username"/>
<property name="password" value="password"/>
<property name="maxActive" value="300"/>
<property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
<property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
<property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
<property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
```

Comment: Insufficient information. We have no way of knowing what your code is doing, what your schema looks like, how your threads are synchronized,  or what contention there might be in the database.  You're going to have to troubleshoot this and narrow it down to something small and concrete enough for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's just normal tomcat thread handled by tomcat. The application is just query database and process data. It works good before, but only after upgrade tomcat & JRE, this problem occurs. I have no idea about this issue also, maybe GC, maybe hibernate, maybe mysql connection. Just want to know if there is any default configuration related to 15minutes26s.

Comment: Is it always the same time ? did you try looking which par of your code was hanging/taking so much time in both thread ?

Comment: Yes, always same suspend time, appeared 141 times per 7 days. The code part should not have problem, since another instance is working fine around half year. I think there must be something wrong with the mysql, server,  jvm configurations. but I have no idea how to debug. if you know there is any default setting around 15mins 26seconds will be helpful.